# Security Errors using Youtube AS3 Chromeless Player

Tags: apache-flex, youtube, flex4

I'm trying to use the Youtube Chromeless Player (the new AS3 version) in a Flex 4-based project. I'm using the [examples provided](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html#Examples) by Google, but I'm not having any luck. The player loads, but it can't be interacted with. I'm receiving repeated security errors just from mousing over the player:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3' tried to access
incompatible context 'file:///Users/jbuhler/Sites/YoutubeTests/bin-debug/YoutubeTest.html'
```

I've tried adding Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com"); to my creationComplete handler before loading the player, and still receive the same errors.

I've also tried using a SWFLoader like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           initialize="onInit()">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        private function onInit ():void
        {
            Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:SWFLoader source="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3" />
</s:Application>
```

I've been at this for a few hours now, and haven't had any success. I also can't seem to find any working examples online. Is this new player just not compatible with Flex 4?

Comment: While I'm still receiving the security errors, I have managed to solve the problem of not interacting with the player - turns out that I was sending the wrong parameters to one of the player methods. I'll leave the question open until I figure out how to resolve the security errors though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error comes from YouTube , see my answer here:
[How to avoid Security Errors when using the Youtube AS3 Player API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785124/how-to-avoid-security-errors-when-using-the-youtube-as3-player-api/3785622#3785622)

Comment: Thinking you're right here - their cross-domain policy file seems off. Luckily all I'm receiving are multiple warnings so the app is at least working. (For the time being.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try accessing your SWF via HTTP from some web server? One running locally might do the trick, or obviously a remote one. There can be security context issues (with the YouTube Player APIs and many other external SWFs as well) when your SWF is accessed via a file:// URI scheme.

Comment: I have tried loading the SWF via HTTP and still receive the same errors. However, I did manage to get the player working like I wanted it to. (Details above.)

Comment: how did you manage to get the mouseEvents working? I cannot see any details above ;-) I'm having the same problem right now...would love to have a solution.