# Flex YouTube API security

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flex4, youtube-api, youtube-channels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Media player using YouTube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148535/media-player-using-youtube)

I have a mobile YouTube API-centric project nearly done. The last view is a component that is a player, naturally, and Flash is not diggin' the security issues at all. Violations, yada yada... And I am passing my developer key in every call too!

So what is the deal with simply loading a video into chromeless player on Android that needs my security attention? Any guesses?

Seriously, I have little prior knowledge of this YouTube API. much less YouTube Flash-to-Flash cross domain 'rules', and there's little out there in the mobile context.

Any help here guys/gals?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check the type of errors you're getting. Is it stopping your application from working,

If no , please check a previous answer given to a similar question.

[How to avoid Security Errors when using the Youtube AS3 Player API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785124/how-to-avoid-security-errors-when-using-the-youtube-as3-player-api)

If yes, you would need to post the type of errors you're getting and should try to read about Flash securities issues.

Comment: The content will not load, the link you refer to doesn't seem to provide at all, it instead trails off into people talking about their development environments crashing, and none of it is in the context of a device. I can execute the some code on the desktop but not the device.